# Does 2-fibre product preserve isomorphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\cal{C}$ be a category. Let $\cal{X}\rightarrow\cal{Z}$ and $\cal{Y}\rightarrow\cal{Z}$ be morphisms of categories over $\cal{C}$. Suppose that the 2-fibre product $\cal{X}\times_{\cal{Z}}\cal{Y}$ exists. If $\cal{X}\rightarrow\cal{Z}$ is an isomorphism, then is $\cal{X}\times_{\cal{Z}}\cal{Y}\rightarrow\cal{Y}$ an isomorphism?

Here is the definition of 2-fibre products in the sense of Stack Project.
[image]

Comment: Do you really mean isomorphisms or rather equivalences of categories?

Comment: Moreover, what do you mean by "2-fibre product"? Is it something that is defined up to isomorphism? If not then it is not even meaningful to ask whether it preserves isomorphisms.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Well.. I mean the 2-fibre products in the sense of Stack Project.

Comment: @Claudius: Yes, I mean isomorphism of categories, which is stronger than equivalence.

Comment: The definition given by Stacks is only up to equivalence. So your question is not well-posed.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: I can not get it. What should I edit my question?

Comment: If you insist on having an answer to the question as written, then the short answer is: no. You can construct an example where $X \to Z$ is an isomorphism but $X \times_Y Z \to Y$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Is there any reference concerning 2-fibre products except Stack Project?

Comment: There are many names for the concept. Bipullback, 2-pullback, bicategorical pullback, iso-comma object, etc. etc. Try searching for the synonyms.

Comment: @Zhen Li: If I change isomorphism to equivalence, then is $\cal{X}\times_{\cal{Y}}\cal{Z}\rightarrow\cal{Y}$ an equivalence?

Comment: Yes. Is that the question you actually want to ask?

Comment: @Zhen Lin: In fact, I have proved a special case that $\cal{X}\times_{\cal{X}}\cal{Y}\rightarrow\cal{Y}$ is an equivalence. But I wonder would happen if I change equivalence to isomorphism.

Comment: If you take the explicit construction as the definition of the 2-fiber product, then $X\times_XY\to Y$ is not an isomorphism, in general. For example, if $G$ is a group, let $C$ be the terminal category (one object, one morphism (=identity)) and let $X = Y = BG$ be the category with one object $*$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{BG}(*,*) = G$. Then the second projection $Z := BG\times_{BG}BG \to BG$ is not an isomorphism for non-trivial $G$, because $\mathrm{ob}(Z) = G$ and $\mathrm{ob}(BG) = \{*\}$.

Comment: @claudius in the notation of OP I think you meant $Z=BG$ as well, with identity morphisms forming the span. No reason not to make that an answer, either.

Answer (score 3):

The 2-fiber product in the $(2,1)$-category of categories is only well-defined up to equivalence. Therefore, as Zhen Lin pointed out in the comments, the question is not well-posed.

However, if we pick the explicit model in the OP as the definition, then the answer is *no*.

To give an example, let $G$ be a non-trivial group. Let $\mathcal C$ be the terminal category and put $\mathcal X = \mathcal Y = \mathcal Z = BG$, that is, the category with one object $*$ and with $\operatorname{Hom}_{BG}(*,*) = G$. The objects of
$$
\mathcal X \times_{\mathcal Z}\mathcal Y = BG\times_{BG}BG
$$
are in bijection with $G$, whereas $BG$ has only one object. Hence, the projection $\mathcal X\times_{\mathcal Z}\mathcal Y \to \mathcal Y$ is not an isomorphism. (But it is fully faithful and essentially surjective, hence an equivalence of categories.)